# cakephp elements and Ajax update

Tags: ajax, cakephp, helper, element

here is what i am trying to achieve...

i have a index view in which i have used the ajax helper not the cakephp one but an external one from  http://www.cakephp.bee.pl/

i  have succefully created an accordion using this helper.

now inside the accordion i have an addbutton which submits a form via ajax.

what i would like to do is when i submit the ajax form. i would also like to update the accordion. 
now the accordion is also created by using the ajax helper.

Can this be done without a page refresh

ajax submit form  code :

```
    <div class="qnotesform">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Qnote');?>
<ul class="qnotelist">
<li><?php   echo $this->Form->input('Qnote.subject', array('label'=>'Title', 'rows' => '1')); ?></li>
<li>    <?php   echo $this->Form->input('Qnote.body', array('label'=>'Header', 'rows' => '1')); ?></li> 
<?php   echo $this->Form->hidden('Qnote.user_id', array('value'=>Authsome::get('id'))); ?>
<?php   echo $this->Form->hidden('Step.0.user_id', array('value'=>Authsome::get('id'))); ?>
<li><?php   echo $this->Form->input('Step.0.body', array('label'=>'Steps' ,'class' => 'step',  'rows' => '1')); ?></li>
</ul>

<?php echo $ajax->submit(
'Submit', array(
'url' => array(
'controller'=>'qnotes',
'action'=>'add')
));
```

how can i achieve this . 
could someone please point me the right direction

another thing that i want to clear out is. If i want to be working one page . and all crud
action to be used without a page refresh.

does anybody have a working example for the above senarios . 
or let me make it simple.
how to refresh a div without refreshing the page.

Solution:

code

```
    <?php echo $ajax->submit('Submit', array(
'url'=> array(
'controller'=>'qnotes',
'action'=>'add'),
'update'=>'leftdiv',
'after'=>'$("#accordion").accordion({autoHeight: false, collapsible: true , header: "h3"});alert("after");',
));
```

however now I am facing another issue now,
I am updating the accordion, everything works fine but as soon as update the accordion. 
the accordion loses its style class and stops working. 
I only see links then.  any idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one of the options in the array of the submit method is 'complete' which should allow you to trigger a js function that will update your accordion:

```
<?php echo $ajax->submit(
'Submit', array(
'url' => array(
'controller'=>'qnotes',
'action'=>'add',
'complete' => 'updateAccordian(request.responseText)')
));
```

the reuqest.responseText will contain the reponse from your controller/action.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that. well I managed to get that ajax to update the accordion... Using the below code. incase someone else needs to refer to it.
have updated the question

Comment: however now I am facing another issue now, I am updating the accordion, everything works fine but as soon as update the accordion. the accordion loses its style class and stops working. I only see links then. any idea how.